# HTML Form elements with matching "name" and "id"?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've a long time habit when coding to name most of the fields in a HTML form with matching "name" and "id" attributes, when possible. This allows me to simplify dynamic HTML generation, f. ex. creating a dropdown in PHP with:

```
select("myselect", $values);
```

instead of:

```
select("myselect", "myselectId", $values)
```

making also my element immediately available for selectors like those in JQuery (for validation etc.).

I know this solution has some issues (it is not good for radio buttons and checkboxes arrays - and for that I include an `$id` parameter in my PHP functions for radios -, it mixes two attributes meant for different purposes, it may cause problems when more than one form is on the page).

Is this bad habit really *that* bad? Have I overlooked some other possible negative side-effects?
What would you do in my place?

- Stick to this whenever it's not causing any problem
- Do not use "ids" at all and use appropriate selectors for JQuery, like `$(form[name='...'] input[name='...']).somefunction()`
- Code in every single element a different id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giving an element matching names and ids does not cause a problem, so you don't need to worry about it and it is not bad practise.

Related things that *do* cause problems:

- Giving multiple elements the same id (e.g. if you have a radio button group where each member has to have the same name).
- Giving one element a name and a different element a matching id

> Do not use "ids" at all

If you don't give a form control an id, then you can't use a `for` attribute to associate it with a `<label>` element. Support for `for` attributes is slightly better then for making the form control a descendent of the label. Since labels are really useful for accessibility (they increase the size of the click target and give a non-visual association between the control and the input) leaving ids off is not a good idea.

Comment: The opposite is also true. :)

Comment: @Diodeus, the opposite of the whole answer? That's kinda hard to imagine. :)

Comment: @Quentin Yes, indeed I've modeled most of my dynamic html-generating functions to include specifications for <label>s (I **hate** when I have to click in a 5x5 pixel area :D), which as you correctly say would be useless without id.
So I guess I'll stick to the old habits, specifying ids only when needed. Thank you for your valued opinion :)